# How to select a bunch of points of a path for removal in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I created a path with a lot of points.  I then duplicated the path so that I can attempt separating them into two smaller paths.

Is there a way to select a bunch of the points as a group to perform an operation on them such as removal?  Or am I forced having to delete each point separately, one at a time.  I would think that the former is a fairly obvious feature because the latter is such a big hassle.

## Edit

Sorry, forgot to mention that the path consists of two strokes and I want to separate the strokes from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers use the [`ofn-path-edits` plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/):

#### Answering the **title** of your question:

Starting with this:

[image]

- Control-Shift-click on the two segments at the ends of the group you want to remove, to delete them and isolate the group as a "stroke".

[image]

- Make a rough free-hand selection arounds one of the ends of the stroke

[image]

- Right-click the path in the Paths list, and `Edit>Delete strokes`.

[image]

#### Answering "I want to separate the strokes from each other."

- Assuming we start with this:

[image]

- Just use `Edit>Break path apart` to get two paths, each with one stroke:

[image]

Comment: So, if I have two strokes in a path.  How would I use this tool to separate the two strokes?

Comment: @Adrian See edited answer

Comment: Cool. Thanks.  That last part is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To get a multiple selection hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on the nodes, and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete all the selected nodes.

If you want to remove a path segment instead, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on the segment. Deletion occurs immediately.

If you find yourself in situations where you are manipulating paths quite often, for example if you are using them to make graphics rather than edit photographs, you might instead want to consider using a vector image editor such as Inkscape (also free and Open Source).

Comment: Yes, I know that I can individually select each node and I said that in my Q.  Doing that is very tedious.  I had outlined an image using paths to create a vectorised image.

Comment: @Adrian No, my answer is on how to select multiple nodes, and delete in one go as opposed to  "having to delete each point separately, one at a time". Sorry if I misunderstood your intent, but there are several ways to interpret your question.

Comment: As a group was meaning in a single operation, not several separate operations where upon you can perform a single operation. I guess it could be considered a little ambiguous.